# Escape correctly this variable string so it doens't output

Tags: linux, io-redirection, command-substitution

I have this shell script:

```
UNZIP_FOUND=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' unzip|grep "install ok installed")
    if [ "" == "$UNZIP_FOUND" ]; then
        echo unzip not found, I will install it
        apt-get --assume-yes install unzip > /dev/null
    fi
```

However this produces me a sentence each time:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching unzip
```

before running the actual installation step.

Is there a way to get rid of it ?

I need to just assign the value of dkpg-query command inside the **UNZIP_FOUND** variable but I don't want to echo it.

I read that the way to do this is surround the variable assignment with ' quotes, I tried to escape the string like this:

```
UNZIP_FOUND='$(dpkg-query -W --showformat=\'${Status}\n\' unzip|grep "install ok installed")'
```

but it doesn't work, probably my escaping was bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do

```
 apt-get --assume-yes install unzip
```

If it's installed, it won't do anything (unless it's outdated in which case it will be upgraded).

If you want it to be quiet, add `--quiet` to that, or redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
apt-get -qq --assume-yes install unzip
```

(`-qq` is "extra quiet", but do see the `apt-get` manual about this flag)

If you really want to query for the existence of the package first, you may do

```
if ! dpkg-query -W unzip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  apt-get --assume-yes install unzip
fi
```

`dpkg-query` exits with a non-zero exit status if it fails to find the package. We redirect both standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` since whatever is written there is not interesting.

---

The reason you get the error message on the terminal is that `dpkg-query` writes it to the standard error stream while your script only captures the standard output stream.

Comment: "dpkg-query exits with a non-zero exit status if it fails to find the package" ok but you negated it in the example above, so shouldn't work in the opposite way?

Comment: @user3450548 In the shell, a zero exit value is "true" while a non-zero exit value is "false". Or you can see it as "zero = this worked" and "non-zero = this failed".

Answer (score 3):

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' unzip 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Oh so the quoted solution was a bad idea ?

Comment: @user3450548 This is nor related to parameter expansion and thus not to quoting. The `$()` does not catch this because it reads only `/dev/stdout` and this is written to `/dev/stderr`. So you have to throw away `stderr` completely.